# query help to find assign group id based on time overlapping and ID

Tags: sql

**This is my test data :**

[image]

**This is the required output:**

[image]

I tried the following :

```
;WITH cte_StepOne as
(
SELECT     id,
    START_TIME,
    END_TIME,
     LAG(Start_TIME, 1) OVER ( ORDER BY id) AS LagStart_TIMEValue,
    LAG(END_TIME, 1) OVER ( ORDER BY id) AS LagEND_TIMEValue
   FROM [ACTIVITY] 
   )

    ,cte_result as 
   (SELECT id,
    START_TIME,
    END_TIME,
    LagStart_TIMEValue,LagEND_TIMEValue,
    CASE 
         WHEN START_TIME between LagStart_TIMEValue AND LagEND_TIMEValue  or 
           END_TIME between LagStart_TIMEValue AND LagEND_TIMEValue 
           and   ID=LAG(ID, 1) OVER (partition by id ORDER BY id)
            THEN ID 

          WHEN LagStart_TIMEValue IS NULL and LagEND_TIMEValue is null THEN ID
        ELSE  id+1 
         END AS OverLapID
   FROM cte_StepOne)

    ,cte_result1 as 
   (SELECT id,
    START_TIME,
    END_TIME,
    LagStart_TIMEValue,LagEND_TIMEValue,
    CASE 
        WHEN LagStart_TIMEValue IS NULL and LagEND_TIMEValue is null THEN OverLapID

         WHEN START_TIME between LagStart_TIMEValue AND LagEND_TIMEValue  or 
           END_TIME between LagStart_TIMEValue AND LagEND_TIMEValue 
           and   OverLapID=LAG(OverLapID, 1) OVER (partition by OverLapID ORDER BY id)
            THEN OverLapID 

         WHEN START_TIME > LagStart_TIMEValue AND END_TIME >LagEND_TIMEValue  
           and   OverLapID=LAG(OverLapID, 1) OVER (partition by OverLapID ORDER BY id)
            THEN OverLapID +1 

                 WHEN START_TIME > LagStart_TIMEValue AND END_TIME <LagEND_TIMEValue  
           and   OverLapID=LAG(OverLapID, 1) OVER (partition by OverLapID ORDER BY id)
            THEN OverLapID +1 


             WHEN LagStart_TIMEValue > START_TIME and  LagEND_TIMEValue >END_TIME  
           and   OverLapID=LAG(OverLapID, 1) OVER (partition by OverLapID ORDER BY id)
            THEN OverLapID+1


             WHEN LagStart_TIMEValue < START_TIME and  LagEND_TIMEValue <END_TIME  
           and   OverLapID=LAG(OverLapID, 1) OVER (partition by OverLapID ORDER BY id)
            THEN OverLapID


        ELSE  OverLapID
         END AS OverLapID
   FROM cte_result)


   SELECT  id,
    START_TIME,
    END_TIME,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY OverLapID) AS GroupID
FROM cte_Result1
ORDER BY id,START_TIME
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gaps and islands problem.  You can identify the "islands" by doing a cumulative max of the end date (ignoring the current row) and then comparing to the current value.  If the cumulative max less than the start in the current row, then the current row starts a new "island".

Then, use a cumulative sum to assign all islands the same value.  And aggregate:

```
select id, min(start), max(end),
      row_number() over (order by id, min(start)) as group_id
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when max_end >= start then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by start) as grp
      from (select t.*
                   max(end) over (partition by id order by start rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as max_end
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, grp
order by id, min(start);
```

Of course, `end` is a very bad name for a column because it is a SQL reserved word.

Comment: It has removed the duplicates values.I want group ID for each group depending on the time overlapping and ID

Comment: @champ . . . I added the calculation for a `group_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT, GROUPID INT,START_TIME  varchar(100),END_TIME  varchar(100))
DECLARE @ID  int,@GROUPID int,@START_TIME  varchar(100),@END_TIME   varchar(100),
  @SEQNO int

DECLARE @Counter INT, @TotalCount INT, @UserId INT;
SET @Counter = 1;

SET @TotalCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM ACTIVITYT_EMP);

WHILE (@Counter <=@TotalCount)
BEGIN

```
SET @START_TIME = (SELECT START_TIME FROM ACTIVITYT_EMP WHERE SEQNO = @Counter)
SET @END_TIME = (SELECT END_TIME FROM ACTIVITYT_EMP WHERE SEQNO = @Counter)
SET @ID = (SELECT ID FROM ACTIVITYT_EMP WHERE SEQNO = @Counter)
SET @GROUPID = 1;

     if (@Counter=1)
      INSERT INTO @Table1 (ID,START_TIME,END_TIME,GROUPID)
        VALUES (@ID,@START_TIME,@END_TIME,@GROUPID)
  else
     if exists (select * from  @Table1 where ID=@ID and  ( (@START_TIME between START_TIME and END_TIME)  or (@END_TIME between START_TIME and END_TIME)  )  )
          begin
         set @GROUPID=(select distinct min(groupid)from @Table1 group by ID,Start_time,end_time having ID=@ID and   ( (@START_TIME between START_TIME and END_TIME)  or (@END_TIME between START_TIME and END_TIME)  )  );
          INSERT INTO @Table1 (ID,START_TIME,END_TIME,GROUPID)
            VALUES (@ID,@START_TIME,@END_TIME,@GROUPID)
         end 
     else
         begin
         set @GROUPID=(select distinct max(groupid)from @Table1)+1 ;
          INSERT INTO @Table1 (ID,START_TIME,END_TIME,GROUPID)
            VALUES (@ID,@START_TIME,@END_TIME,@GROUPID)

         end 


SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
CONTINUE;
```

END
SELECT * FROM @Table1 order by groupid
delete from  @Table1